# Is it a good practice to call action within another action (in flux)

Tags: flux, reactjs-flux

I have an action as follows:

```
SomeActions.doAction1(){
   //..dispatch event "started"...
   //...do some process....
   FewActions.doAnotherAction(); //CAN WE DO THIS
   //...do something more....
   //..dispatch event "completed"..
}
```

While the above works with no problems, just wondering, if it is valid according to flux pattern/standard or is there a better way.

Also, I guess calling Actions from Stores are a bad idea.  Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, calling an Action within another Action is a bad practice.  Actions should be atomic; all changes in the Stores should be in response to a single action.  They should describe one thing that happened in the real world: the user clicked on a button, the server responded with data, the screen refreshed, etc.

Most people get confused by Actions when they are thinking about them as *imperative* instructions (first do A, then do B) instead of descriptions of what happened and the starting point for *reactive* processes.

This is why I recommend to people that they name their Action types in the past tense: `BUTTON_CLICKED`.  This reminds the programmer of the fundamentally externally-driven, descriptive nature of Actions.

Actions are like a newspaper that gets delivered to all the stores, describing what happened.

Calling Actions from Stores is almost always the wrong thing to do.  I can only think of one exception: when the Store responds to the first Action by starting up an asynchronous process.  When the async process completes, you want to fire off a second Action.  This is the case with a XHR call to the server.  But the better way is to put the XHR handling code into a Utils module.  The store can then respond to the first Action by calling a method in the Utils module, and then the Utils module has the code to call the second Action when the server response comes back.